# What other documents other than Passport are considered an ID when applying for renewing the residency in Germany?

Tags: germany, residency, blue-card

Is Passport the only acceptable form of ID that I can use to renew my residency in Germany, or there other alternatives that can be presented as an ID?
And what if I have to renew my residency but my Passport is expired and I cannot renew it quickly due to some complications at my Embassy?